# How can we count the time of process?

Tags: gwt, timer, popup

I created a `PopupPanel` and have shown it. I want to hide it after one minute has passed. During that one minute, the process should not be stopped or paused. How can I achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GWT has its own implementation of [`Timer`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/Timer.html).

Here a really small example:

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
    final PopupPanel popUp = new PopupPanel();
    Label text = new Label("gone in a sec");
    popUp.setWidget(text);

    Timer timer = new Timer() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            popUp.hide();
        }

    };

    popUp.center();
    timer.schedule(3000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use: [java.util.Timer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html)

And you can do something like this:

```
int seconds = 60;
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new YourScheduledTask(), seconds * 1000);
```

Exmaple: [Use java.util.Timer to schedule a task to execute once 5 seconds have passed](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/UsejavautilTimertoscheduleatasktoexecuteonce5secondshavepassed.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Thread.sleep(60000);`

But be careful you have to chose the correct thread to pause. And exception handling also has to be added.