# How to hide a popup after time elapses in Java/GWT

Tags: java, gwt, timer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can we count the time of process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4041448/how-can-we-count-the-time-of-process)

I have a pop-up dialog that pops up after a user had saved a value. I want the popup to disappear after 2 seconds. Somthing like

```
if(timeElapsed(2 seconds)){
    popup.hide()
}
```

The related questions I saw measure the running time of a function. How can I run a dummy loop for 2 seconds and then call the hide function?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a Timer in your popup panel. Next you can init the Timer in the show() method like this:

```
Timer t = new Timer() {
  public void run() {
    Popup.this.hide();
  }
}

t.schedule(2000);
```

This will start the timer when the popup is first showed. When the timer expires, the popup will be hidden.

Eventually you can define the timer as a global variable in the popup and use a boolean to see if the timer is running, so that if you need to display the popup again while an instance is still showing, you won't start a new timer.